# Intellij plugin open new class in editor after creation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am writing an intellij plugin. after i create a Java class I would like to open the newly created file in the editor. How should I go at this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was as follows:

```
 // we create the actual class
 final VirtualFile newFile = JavaDirectoryService.getInstance().createClass(directory, className, templateName).getContainingFile().getVirtualFile();
 // open to the new file in the editor
 FileEditorManager.getInstance(project).openFile(newFile, true, true);
```